# How to replace Unicode values using re in Python?

Tags: python, regex

How to replace unicode values using re in Python ? 
I'm looking for something like this:

```
line.replace('Ã','')
line.replace('¢','')
line.replace('Ã¢','')
```

Or is there any way which will replace all the non-ASCII characters from a file. Actually I converted PDF file to ASCII, where I'm getting some non-ASCII characters [e.g. bullets in PDF]

Please help me.

Comment: Please respect language, you are not on IRC.

Comment: Even on IRC it is not appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit after feedback in comments.**

Another solution would be to check the numeric value of each character and see if they are under 128, since ascii goes from 0 - 127. Like so:

```
# coding=utf-8

def removeUnicode():
    text = "hejsanäöåbadasd wodqpwdk"
    asciiText = ""
    for char in text:
        if(ord(char) < 128):
            asciiText = asciiText + char

    return asciiText

import timeit
start = timeit.Timer("removeUnicode()", "from __main__ import removeUnicode")
print "Time taken: " + str(start.timeit())
```

Here's an altered version of `jd`'s answer with benchmarks:

```
# coding=utf-8

def removeUnicode():
    text = u"hejsanäöåbadasd wodqpwdk"
    if(isinstance(text, str)):
        return text.decode('utf-8').encode("ascii", "ignore")
    else:
        return text.encode("ascii", "ignore")        

import timeit
start = timeit.Timer("removeUnicode()", "from __main__ import removeUnicode")
print "Time taken: " + str(start.timeit())
```

Output first solution using a `str` string as input:

```
computer:~ Ancide$ python test1.py
Time taken: 5.88719677925
```

Output first solution using a `unicode` string as input:

```
computer:~ Ancide$ python test1.py
Time taken: 7.21077990532
```

Output second solution using a `str` string as input:

```
computer:~ Ancide$ python test1.py
Time taken: 2.67580914497
```

Output second solution using a `unicode` string as input:

```
computer:~ Ancide$ python test1.py
Time taken: 1.740680933
```

### Conclusion

Encoding is the faster solution and encoding the string is less code; Thus the better solution.

Comment: Your benchmarks are useless. You should always use `timeit` for timing Python stuff; (a) it measures just the actual code, not interpreter initialisation and destruction, and (b) it does many runs. As you *should* expect, `unicode.encode()` is oodles faster. about 0.889, while your `removeUnicode` takes over 7; even dealing with a `str` with `str.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'ignore')` is not too bad, around 2.5 (`str.decode('ascii', 'ignore')` is slow, about 13.3).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Chris. I've edited my answer according to your feedback. Are you content with my edit?

Comment: yep, it'll do; I'd recommend using just `timeit.timeit(removeUnicode)` instead of instantiating a `Timer` object as it's shorter and easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode your Unicode string to ASCII, ignoring any error that occurs. Here's how:

```
>>> u'uéa&à'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'ua&'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to replace if you have

```
title.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
```

or if you want to ignore

```
unicode(title, errors='replace')
```

Comment: You typed 'replace' for ignore

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass re.UNICODE flag to params. Like this:

`re.compile("pattern", re.UNICODE)`

For more info see [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) page.